# How do I mirror an object on the -x axis?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, mirror, mirror-modifier

I am using the Mirror modifier to mirror an object.

Normal:
[image: Normal model]

Mirrored:
[image: Mirrored mode]

The model is mirroring the wrong way, however. Is there any way to mirror on the -x axis as opposed to the +x axis?

Comment: it is using the object origin as mirror center, so what you can do is select the mesh in Edit mode and move it on the other side of the origin (to the left), or move the origin

Comment: Mirror uses by default the object origin as center.  Either move the object origin or use another object (an empty) as "mirror object" in the modifier.

Comment: @lemon I tried moving the origin but there was no difference

Comment: Wait nevermind... it works perfectly now simply by clicking in the middle, using "origin to 3D cursor". I'm an idiot!